# How to write directive with custom prefix ? so something different than `v-`?

Tags: vue.js

Is there any way in vue.js 2.x to define a directive WITHOUT the `v-` prefix ? All our angular 1 directives already have a prefix and when converting we dont want to (and also dont think it to be sensible) to share the vue scoped prefix. We have directives like `rs-fullscreen` which belong to our i**r**i**s** domain. just like we didn't use `ng` for our angular directives.

Answer (score 4):

Straight answer: This is not possible and won't be anytime soon, if ever.

Comment: good to know, but why ? the mixing of namespaces sound like an uncommon position and prefixing everything with v-mynamespace-mydirective doesn't sound very appealing either.

Comment: btw. good to see members of the core team respond to questions on stackoverflow (though I did not expect that during the holidays ;) )

We are considering vue as a long term choice and walk through the applications we built on our platform to check typical migration points for the angular 1 designs to vue. For now it looks pretty good, especially when compared to angular 2.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "mixing of namespaces" in this context. The general reasoning for `v-` was to have a common prefix for all vue-related directives, which makes it easy to navigate any Vue template no matter the project, and makes it easy to parse templates technically, as well. Introducing custom prefixes would require a per-component definition of said prefix to keep components re-usable as plugins etc.

Comment: We already have a number of helper attribute level directives we offer in our system to designers. in angular 1 they could look at each directive and look documentation up by the prefix.if it was ng-* it was pure angular, if it was rs-* it was ours if it was md-* it was material design etc. When starting with vue per default it would just add an extra v- so v-rs-*. We would do away with rs- and just have v- but this will cause confusion as to where to look up the documentation.we architected our system so that looking at the html only should give a general overview of the dependencies already.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. This comes from the fact that a typical angular app would make heavy use of custom directives. In Vue 2.0, you won't (apart from the builtin ones, `v-for` etc.). The functionality of custom directives in Vue is *much* smaller than in Angular, and only targeted at low-level DOM work (which you should hardly have to do). Most things that you have solved with a directive in angular, you will solve with a component in vue - and you can name components whatever you want. And because of this, namespacing directives is not really useful/necessary.

Comment: ok, thanks for that answer :) We are in the process of rewriting our platform from angular 1 to vue (experimental), so far we are very pleased with it (the documentation, the organization, the priorities). it swayed us from angular 2, but its still high risk so forgive all these questions please :)

Comment: Nothing to forgive here :)